# Can the "using" declaration be used with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, using

Is it possible to use the "using" declaration with template base classes? I have read it isn't [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/using_declaration_class_members.htm#using_declaration_class_members) but is that because of a technical reason or is it against the C++ standard, and does it apply to gcc or other compilers?  If it is not possible, why not?

Example code (from the link above):

```
struct A {
    template<class T> void f(T);
};

struct B : A {
    using A::f<int>;
};
```

Comment: Can you add a little more info to your question?  What exactly do you think is illegal?  The link mentions nothing about templates

Comment: Jared, I've corrected the link.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I copied the link from the address bar and it was the wrong one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you linked to is a using directive. A using declaration can be used fine with templated base classes (haven't looked it up in the standard, but just tested it with a compiler):

```
template<typename T> struct c1 { 
    void foo() { std::cout << "empty" << std::endl; } 
}; 

template<typename T> struct c2 : c1<T> { 
    using c1<T>::foo; 
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; } 
}; 

int main() { 
    c2<void> c;
    c.foo();
    c.foo(10); 
}
```

The compiler correctly finds the parameter-less `foo` function because of our using-declaration re-declaring it into the scope of `c2`, and outputs the expected result.

**Edit**: updated the question. here is the updated answer:

The article is right about that you are not allowed to use a template-id (template name and arguments). But you can put a template name:

```
struct c1 { 
    template<int> void foo() { std::cout << "empty" << std::endl; } 
}; 

struct c2 : c1 { 
    using c1::foo; // using c1::foo<10> is not valid
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; } 
}; 

int main() { 
    c2 c;
    c.foo<10>();
    c.foo(10); 
}
```

Comment: This is something else. The OP probably meant a member function template residing in the base class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the using thing.  Is it possible to call foo from within a c2 method without having to specify the base class, ie "foo()" instead of "c1<T>::foo()"?

Comment: Sydius, yes you do this->foo(); the foo is in the baseclass, and that one depends on a template parameter. the standard says the call has to be qualified either with the scope operator (c1<T>::foo()) or using this->foo();. otherwise it assumes "foo" is a global function